# Single class image classification using deep learning

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, image-classification

I am familiar with binary and multi classification problems using CNNs but not sure how to build a classifier to classify an image as 'object' or 'not object' without overfitting when my train data has a single label (i.e. only images that contain 'object').

What I want to do is similar to what was done [here](https://www.kaggle.com/paperboiii/one-class-classification-for-images) but I am only allowed to use CNN for training and cannot add other images to the dataset.

Comment: Could you select an empty part of your images and use them as "no object" class examples?

Comment: What do you mean by "empty part" of the images. Do you mean images that doesn't contain the object. Will that be a right thing to do,  knowing the algorithm would learn the features of such images and look out for such specific features during testing.

Comment: yes, I meant images with no-object inside